# Multisampling and Direct3D10 / D3DImage interop

Tags: interop, multisampling, direct3d10, d3dimage

I'm trying to implement a renderengine using Direct3D 10 (SlimDX) and WPF.

I create my device and rendertargetview with the right MultiSample parameters ( 1,0 / 2,0 and 4,0 are working)

```
        this.multiSamplingDescription = new SampleDescription(sampleCount, qualityLevel - 1); // 4,1

        Texture2DDescription colordesc = new Texture2DDescription();
        colordesc.BindFlags = BindFlags.RenderTarget | BindFlags.ShaderResource;
        colordesc.Format = this.renderTargetViewFormat; // Format.B8G8R8A8_UNorm
        colordesc.Width = width;
        colordesc.Height = height;
        colordesc.MipLevels = 1;
        colordesc.SampleDescription = multiSamplingDescription;
        colordesc.Usage = ResourceUsage.Default;
        colordesc.OptionFlags = ResourceOptionFlags.Shared;
        colordesc.CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.None;
        colordesc.ArraySize = 4;[/code]
```

Then I've got a problem while trying to create the shared texture for D3DImage ...

```
        this.Direct3D9Context = new Direct3DEx();
        this.presentParams = new PresentParameters();
        this.presentParams.Windowed = true;
        this.presentParams.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard;
        this.presentParams.DeviceWindowHandle = GetDesktopWindow();
        this.presentParams.PresentationInterval = PresentInterval.Immediate;
        this.presentParams.Multisample = MultisampleType.None;
        this.presentParams.MultisampleQuality = 0;

        this.Device = new DeviceEx(this.Direct3D9Context, 0, DeviceType.Hardware, IntPtr.Zero, CreateFlags.HardwareVertexProcessing | CreateFlags.Multithreaded | CreateFlags.FpuPreserve, this.presentParams);
```

...

```
        this.presentParams.Multisample = sampleCount; // = 4
        this.presentParams.MultisampleQuality = 0;
        this.Device.Reset(this.presentParams);
```

...

```
        this.SharedTexture = new Texture(this.Device, texture.Description.Width, texture.Description.Height, 1, Usage.RenderTarget, format, Pool.Default, ref Handle);

// format = Format.A8R8G8B8
// Width = 1244 , same as colordesc
// height = 699, same as colordesc
```

I'm missing something ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc663104.aspx

"Multisampling is allowed on IDirect3DSurface9Ex surfaces only."

But this interface IDirect3DSurface9Ex doesnt seem to exist !

Comment: do you succeed finally ?

Comment: IDirect3DDevice9Ex is described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174337(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Maxence That page makes no mention of anything called IDirect3D***Surface9***Ex, so qventura's question still remains. Could it be a typo on the MSDN page for D3DImage?